# Get report of all assets from YouTube Content ID API

Tags: youtube-api

I represent a YouTube content owner and I use the YouTube Reporting API to get daily analytical reports on how well our many thousands of assets perform on YouTube.

Those reports only give an asset ID to reference the actual real world asset ie musical sound recording. I plan to read those reports, in bulk, into a streaming platform to get analytics of how the assets are performing. The issue I have is that, in order to match the analytics to the actual sound recording, I need a list of all the assets for which we have control.

I see the YouTube Content ID API gives access to asset lists through their `assets` and `assetSearch` resources. The thing is neither really work as the `assets` resource requires knowledge of the asset IDs already and `assetSearch` returns a paginated list of only 25 at a time.

What would be best for me would be a CSV of all the assets that I could pass into the streaming platform in one go rather than having to hit a search endpoint thousands of times to get an up-to-date list.

I don't really want to have to build a secondary service to have a database of those assets. It would make far more sense to get an up-to-date list all in one go every day. Is that something that any of the APIs offer?

All other streaming platforms offer some data with their analytics to help us identify what sound recording this relates to, but YouTube seem to make it difficult.

Answer (score -1):

What kind of KPI's do you want to track of those assets? Views or revenue?

In case if its revenue, you could use the Reporting API to get the system-managed reports of the assets and parse and calculate the revenue accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't see how the KPIs are relevant. I use the reporting API to get information on both views and revenue. However, those reports don't give any asset information beyond asset ID. My aim is to match reported metrics to music in our own system. For that we need information attached to the asset (ISRC, asset title, artists, etc). That information seems to only be available through the endpoints I mentioned in my question.